Render window is empty when not pushing any game object into a vector
I am trying SDL2 Gamedev for the first time so I don't know the best practices yet.
Now, I have a code structure which looks something like this:

main.cpp
ui

button.cpp and button.hpp
objects.cpp and objects.hpp
rectangle.cpp and rectangle.hpp
shapes.cpp and shapes.hpp



The shapes class is the base class for all the render-able objects (for example Rects, buttons, etc) and the object class holds all those objects in a std::vector.
Now a problem arises when I try to append an object into the vector
The append logic:

if the object has a unique ID which is not yet in the vector push the element into the vector
else if the unique ID is there in the vector do nothing and return false

When I add all unique elements to the vector the renderer renders everything as it should. But when it finds a duplicate it does not call the push function and as a result the window goes black.
This is my objects.cpp:
#include "objects.hpp"

Objects::Objects()
{
}

Objects::~Objects()
{
    // No need to explicitly clear the container; the unique_ptrs will be cleaned up automatically
}

bool Objects::addShapeObject(std::unique_ptr<Shape> shape)
{
    for (const auto& existingShape : this->shapesObjectContainer)
    {
        if (shape->getUID() == existingShape->getUID())
        {
            printf("Can't add duplicate OBJECTS\nERR: Same UID ->>> %s\n", shape->getUID().c_str());
            return false; // Duplicate found, return false
        }
    }

    this->shapesObjectContainer.push_back(std::move(shape));
    printf("Was able to push object\n");
    return true; // Successfully added
}

void Objects::updateObjects(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    for (const auto& shape : this->shapesObjectContainer)
    {
        shape->update(renderer); // Use smart pointer access
    }
}

And here is my buttons.cpp:
#include "buttons.hpp"
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

Button::~Button() {
    if (textSurface) {
        SDL_FreeSurface(textSurface);
        textSurface = nullptr; // Avoid dangling pointer
    }
    if(textTexture)
    {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(textTexture);
        textTexture = nullptr;
    }
    if(renderer)
    {
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        renderer = nullptr;
    }
    if (tFont) {
        TTF_CloseFont(tFont);
        tFont = nullptr; // Avoid dangling pointer
    }
    TTF_Quit();
}

Button::Button(int coords[4], int colorRGB[3], SDL_Renderer *gRenderer, std::string UID, const char textString[])
    : Rectangle(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2], coords[3], UID),UniqueIdentifier(UID),renderer(gRenderer),textDest ({coords[0],coords[1],coords[2],coords[3]})
{
    this->setColor(colorRGB[0],colorRGB[1],colorRGB[2]);
    if(TTF_Init() == -1)
    {
        printf("TTF_Init: %s\n", TTF_GetError());
    }

    this->tFont = TTF_OpenFont("ui/resources/default.ttf",24);
    if(!tFont)
    {
        printf("Can not load the TTF file \n");
    }
    else
    {
        this->foregroundColor = {0x30,0x30,0x30};
        this->textString = textString;
        this->textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(this->tFont, textString, this->foregroundColor);
        if(!this->textSurface)
        {
            printf("Could not initilized text surface");
        }
        this->textTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer,this->textSurface);

    }
        this->defaultColor = this->getColor();
        this->defColorArr[0] = defaultColor[0];
        this->defColorArr[1] = defaultColor[1];
        this->defColorArr[2] = defaultColor[2];
}

void Button::update(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    this->draw(renderer);
    printf("Rendering for UID %s \n",this->UniqueIdentifier.c_str());
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,this->textTexture, NULL ,&(this->textDest));
}

void Button::clickHandler(SDL_Event e, std::function<void()> caller)
{
    int X,Y = 0;
    SDL_GetMouseState(&X,&Y);
    if(X >= this->x && X <= this->x + this->w && Y >= this->y && Y <= this->y + this->h)
    {
        if(e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            if (caller != nullptr) {
                caller();  // Call the function
            }       
            this->setColor(0x62,0x62,0x72);
        }
        else
        {
        this->setColor(0x92,0x92,0x92);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this->setColor(this->defColorArr[0],this->defColorArr[1],this->defColorArr[2]);
    }
}

void Button::setText(char textString[])
{
    this->textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(this->tFont, textString, this->foregroundColor);    
    this->textTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(this->renderer,this->textSurface);
    this->textString = textString;
}
std::string Button::getUID()
{
    return std::string(this->UniqueIdentifier);
}
void Button::setText(std::string textString)
{
    this->textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(this->tFont, textString.c_str(), this->foregroundColor);    
    this->textTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(this->renderer,this->textSurface);
    this->textString = textString;
}

std::string Button::getText()
{
    return this->textString;
}

And my rectangle.cpp:
#include "rectangle.hpp"

// Constructor definition
Rectangle::Rectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h,std::string UID):UniqueIdentifier(UID)
    ,x(x), y(y), w(w), h(h) {
}

// Method to set the color of the rectangle
void Rectangle::setColor(Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b) {
    color[0] = r;
    color[1] = g;
    color[2] = b;
}

int* Rectangle::getColor()
{
    return color;
}

// Method to draw the rectangle
void Rectangle::draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer) const {
    if (renderer == nullptr) {
        printf("Renderer is null, cannot draw rectangle.\n");
        return;
    }
    // SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xff); // Full opacity

    // Define an SDL_Rect structure with the rectangle's properties
    SDL_Rect fillRect = { x, y, w, h };
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, color[0], color[1], color[2], 0xFF );        
    SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &fillRect );
}

my files structure:
SDL git:(main) ✗ ls
Makefile             SDL2_image.framework loaded.png           main.o               ui
Readme.md            a.txt                main                 mysql                your_program
SDL2.framework       deb                  main.cpp             steps.txt
➜  SDL git:(main) ✗ 

The problem arises when I do not use:
this->shapesObjectContainer.push_back(std::move(shape));

Because if I comment the if statement and then allow all the duplicate to be in the vector then the renderer work finer but I if comment the push line the renderer does not show anything.
main.cpp:
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ui/buttons.hpp"
#include "ui/rectangle.hpp"
#include "ui/objects.hpp"
#include <string>

//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

//Starts up SDL and creates window
bool init();

//Loads media
//Frees media and shuts down SDL
void close();

void showModal(SDL_Window* parent) {
    SDL_Window* modal = SDL_CreateWindow("What is on your Todo", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 300, 200, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    
    // Render dialog contents here (e.g., buttons, text, etc.)

    bool modalRunning = true;
    SDL_Event e;
    
    while (modalRunning) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                modalRunning = false;
            }
            // Handle other events (e.g., button clicks)
            if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
                // Close modal on click for demonstration
                modalRunning = false;
            }
        }
        // You would render your dialog content here
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(modal);
}

//Loads individual image as texture
SDL_Texture* loadTexture( std::string path );

//The window we'll be rendering to
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

//The window renderer
SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;

//Current displayed texture
SDL_Texture* gTexture = NULL;

bool init()
{
    //Initialization flag
    bool success = true;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Set texture filtering to linear
        if( !SDL_SetHint( SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1" ) )
        {
            printf( "Warning: Linear texture filtering not enabled!" );
        }

        //Create window
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "Timeit", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( gWindow == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Create renderer for window
            gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
            if( gRenderer == NULL )
            {
                printf( "Renderer could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Initialize renderer color
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0xFF );
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}

void close()
{
    //Free loaded image
    SDL_DestroyTexture( gTexture );
    gTexture = NULL;

    //Destroy window    
    SDL_DestroyRenderer( gRenderer );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
    gWindow = NULL;
    gRenderer = NULL;

    //Quit SDL subsystem
    SDL_Quit();
}

SDL_Texture* loadTexture( std::string path )
{
    //The final texture
    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;

    //Load image at specified path


    return newTexture;
}

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //Start up SDL and create window
    if( !init() )
    {
        printf( "Failed to initialize!\n" );
    }
    else
    {
            //Main loop flag
            bool quit = false;
            Objects objects(gRenderer);

            //Event handler
            SDL_Event e;
            int coords[4] = {SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - 25, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 160,50, 20};
            int coords2[4] = {SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - 25, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 260,50, 20};
            int buttonColor[3] = {0xc2, 0xbf, 0xaf};
            objects.addShapeObject(std::make_unique<Button>(coords, buttonColor, gRenderer,"Timer Button", "Start"));
            objects.addShapeObject(std::make_unique<Button>(coords2, buttonColor, gRenderer,"Timer Button", "Start"));

            // printf("UID :%i\n",testButton->UniqueIdentifier);
            // seed48()

            Uint32 startTime = SDL_GetTicks();  // Time at start of the loop
            int frameCount = 0;                 // Number of frames rendered
            float fps = 0.0f;                   // FPS value


            //While application is running
            while( !quit )
            {
                //Handle events on queue
                SDL_Delay(2);
                while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
                {
                    //User requests quit
                    // testButton->clickHandler(e,[&testButton](){
                    //  if(testButton->getText() == "Stop")
                    //  {
                    //      testButton->setText("Start");
                    //  }
                    //  else
                    //  {
                    //      testButton->setText("Stop");
                    //  }
                    // });
                    if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
                    {
                        quit = true;
                    }
                    if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_m) {
                        showModal(gWindow);
                    }
                }

                //Clear screen
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0xFF); // Set the clear color
                SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer); // Clear the screen with the clear color

                // Your drawing code
                SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, gTexture, NULL, NULL); // Draw the texture

                // Set a different color for points
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0x7F, 0x2F, 0xFF, 0xFF);
                for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT; i += 4) {
                    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(gRenderer, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, i);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_WIDTH; i += 4) {
                    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(gRenderer, i, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2);
                }

                objects.updateObjects(gRenderer); // Render your objects
                SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer); // Present the back buffer
                printf("%s\n", SDL_GetError());

                if(gRenderer == nullptr)
                {
                    printf("gRenderer is no more");
                }

                frameCount++;

            // Calculate FPS every second
                Uint32 currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();
                if (currentTime - startTime >= 1000) {
                    // Calculate FPS
                    fps = frameCount / ((currentTime - startTime) / 1000.0f);

                    // Reset timer and frame count for next second
                    startTime = currentTime;
                    frameCount = 0;

                    // Output FPS to console (you can render this to the screen if needed)
                    printf("FPS: %.2f\n", fps);
                }

            }
        }
    //Free resources and close SDL
    close();

    return 0;
}

The console shows Parameter 'renderer' is invalid

I got it,
The solution was
shapes.release();

The reason for the unwanted issues was that once the addShapesFunction was call when there were no duplicate is move the shape into the vector while if there were no objects the shape object was in a dangling state by calling the release method I cleared that dangling pointer and the issue was resolved.

You should now be able to click the ✅ icon to the left of your answer to mark it as "Accepted", showing that it solved your problem.

That is not something you need to tag me about, @agone. If your assessment is that the question does not contain a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, then you can cast a close vote using thr "Close" link above.

@agone Ah, at your rep level, the corresponding action would be "Flag" — then select the "needs improvement" option. This puts your feedback in a queue that can be handled by any user with the required privileges, rather than being visible only to the user you @-mentioned. You can also apply a down-vote to posts you deem to be insufficient quality or unhelpful, though it's generally considered polite to also/instead comment to offer the poster constructive feedback about what they can update to improve the post, or do better in future posts.
